# How to get the two best students of each professor in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 3 fields like this:

```
ProfessorID    StudentID    Mark
P1             S1              9
P1             S2              8
P1             S3             10
P2             S1              7
P2             S2              2
P2             S3              4
P3             S4              5
P4             S1              6
```

A professor can teach many students, and vice versa, a student can learn from many professor. When a student learns from a professor, he gets his mark.

My problem is showing list of professors who teach at least 2 students, and 2 students who get best marks from those professors. In example, the query result of this table is:

```
ProfessorID    StudentID    Mark
P1             S1              9
P1             S3             10
P2             S1              7
P2             S3              4
```

I've tried some solutions but they don't work **right**.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: It's tagged as homework, post what you tried, will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare  @table table (ProfessorID nvarchar(2), StudentID nvarchar(2),Mark int)

insert into @table
select 'P1', 'S1', 9
union all
select 'P1', 'S2', 8
union all
select 'P1', 'S3', 10
union all
select 'P2', 'S1', 7
union all
select 'P2', 'S2', 2
union all
select 'P2', 'S3', 4
union all
select 'P3', 'S4', 5
union all
select 'P4', 'S1', 6

select *
from @table o
where o.StudentID IN (select top 2 s.StudentID from @table s where s.ProfessorId = o.ProfessorId order by Mark DESC)
and o.ProfessorID IN (select p.ProfessorID from @table p group by p.ProfessorID having count(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Interesting... will have to look at this again when I'm more awake.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you want it in SQL 2005 (or 2008), this will work as well

```
select *
from
(
select *
    ,rank() over  (partition by professorid order by mark desc) as ranking
    ,(select count(distinct studentid) 
        from marks m2 
        where m2.professorid = m1.professorid 
        group by professorid
        ) as students
from marks m1
) subs
where ranking < 3
and students > 2
```

-Edoode

Answer (score 0):

I just woke up... but here goes:

```
select *
FROM 
   (select professorID, count(distinct studentID) as studentsTaught
    FROM table
    ) s
WHERE s.studentsTaught = 2
UNION ALL    
SELECT top 2 *
FROM table
WHERE professorID IN (select professorID
                      FROM (
                            select professorID, count(distinct studentID) as studentsTaught
                            FROM table
                            ) s
                      )
WHERE s.studentsTaught = 2
ORDER BY mark
```

Should work... basically you're querying the professors and counting them as a subquery, then selecting the ones who have 2 students from that subquery.  For their students you have to UNION them and find the same professors, but ORDER BY is good enough to get the two best students.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ProfessorID, StudentID, MAX(Mark)
FROM table
GROUP BY ProfessorID, StudentID
```

Comment: That won't restrict by professors with two or more more students, nor restrict to the top 2 scores.